# D3 forcelayout label overlap with link

Tags: d3.js, hyperlink, hover, label

I would like to display tooltip when hover a link

But sometimes the text of label of node got in the way--> no longer the mouse focus in hovering link.

Is there any way to completely ignore the label and let the link hovering happens as expected? Just like the label is not there (still display) anymore

Comment: Dirty solution: add an invisible link (opacity = 0) on top of the original one, after the node labels in the dom structure, and trigger the tool-tip when mouseover'ing the invisible link. Bonus: you can even make this link thicker, to make it easier to mouse over

Comment: Woa, i think it is brilliant, a little bit hacky though. I will try it and report back here